# only characters in IE8 html text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I want to restrict user to enter only characters in a html text box. I am using the following code

```
 $('.alphaonly').live("input", function () {
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-zÀ-ÿ ]/g, ''));
 });
```

and this works fine in IE9, but fails in IE8.

Can anyone help me fixing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is much easier to use a plugin I mean:

http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input

```
$('#text_input').filter_input({regex:'[a-z]'});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `keyup` and `mouseup` event for older browsers:

```
 $('.alphaonly').on("keyup mouseup input", function () {
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-zÀ-ÿ ]/g, ''));
 });​
```

The `input` event is not supported in IE < 9. You can accomplish *almost* the same functionality using `keyup` and `mouseup`. Also, as of jQuery 1.7, `.live()` is deprecated in favor of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QL8Mh/)**.

Comment: True, but you might add the `input` and `mouseup` events to recognize `paste` etc.

Comment: Thanks , but we tried this approach. the problem with keyup, keydown is that we can see the input. while in Input event user cannot see numbers he typed.

Comment: @SujithKp: Yes, that's the *problem* with `keyup`. Have you tried this plugin http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event? It provides a cross-browser implementation of the `input` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this ...
$('.alphaonly').live({
   keyup : function () {
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-zÀ-ÿ ]/g, ''));
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//If you consider doing it plain JavaScript way, without JQuery      
 function lettersOnly(evt) {
   evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
   var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :
      ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
   if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
      (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
      alert("Enter letters only.");
      return false;
   }
   return true;
 }
```